# 95 Honda civic reset timing

Tags: honda, civic, troubleshooting, timing-belt, timing

Recently did a head gasket change and once it was done found out the engine didn't want to start anymore. Diagnosed it a bit, and found out the timing was off about a tooth on the cam gear. I was told to remove the gear, and rotate it a bit, but I was wondering how else could I reset the timing, or change it a bit. Would I have to untension it and rotate the cam? Any suggestions or help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I'm going to vote to close this because I answered it in your other question. This one is redundant.

Comment: You can close it haha, saw the answer, answered everything and more, thanks!